# Why grid overflows the parent grid when it contains an overflowing item?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

When wide item is positioned within a grid (red, in the picture below), the grid preserves its width.

However, when there is another grid in the game (blue, in the picture below), it overflows the parent grid, and adding `width: 100%` to it doesn't seem to help.

Why is this happening?

How would you ensure that the blue grid doesn't overflow the red container?

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.grid1 {
  display: grid;
  border: 10px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.grid2 {
  display: grid;
  border: 10px solid blue;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid1">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid1">
    <div class="grid2">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want the blue one to be like the red one ?

Comment: or just have both of them inside the .container

Comment: `min-width: 0;` to the blue item

Comment: Because, by default, a grid item cannot be shorter than its content. As @TemaniAfif has just noted, override the `min-width: auto` default. https://jsfiddle.net/z3bf2whp/